# Keyword of Styles in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, fonts, colors, background

I'm customizing my Font and Colors of Visual Studio and I don't know how to change the background color of the item when the cursor stops on a type (class, interfance, structs  etc...) and the other same types change the background like in the image. I would like to know how is the keyword in Tools->Options->Fonts and Colors->Displays Items ?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **Highlighted Reference**

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

[Visual Studio Programmer Themes Gallery by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioProgrammerThemesGallery.aspx)

You can choose different styles that suites you.

Hope this help.

Regards

Comment: Yes, I take this style from www.studiostyl.es. This is Son of Obsidian, the most popular! But I would like to customiza this background-color item (when the cursor stop on a type and it highlighter the background of all same types) ?